# 'Foo' has not been declared , but file with it included

Tags: c++, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I'm having 2 .h files ( with .cpp files ) that has code like that:

Foo:

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_FOO_H_
#define INCLUDE_FOO_H_

class Foo
{
    public:
        virtual ~Foo();
        virtual void workWithBar(Bar* bar);
};

#endif /* INCLUDE_FOO_H_ */
```

Bar:

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_BAR_H_
#define INCLUDE_BAR_H_

class Bar
{
    public:
        virtual ~Bar();
        virtual void letsWorkWithFoo(Foo* itsFoo);
};

class Bar2 : public Bar
{
    public:
        virtual void letsWorkWithFoo(Foo* itsFoo);
};
#endif /* INCLUDE_BAR_H_ */
```

cpp files are just simple files , with "empty" impl. of that code. I'm using latest Eclipse , and latest MinGW that i could find. Both of cpp files include  and . If i put all that classes together , it would compile and work fine. And i'm using Foo.h in main.cpp too , and its working perfect too.

I did try adding include into Foo & Bar , i did try using diffrent std(-std=c++11). I'm not using "using namespace" anywhere in .h files.

p.s. if you didnt undestend it from title -

```
C:\PathWasHere\include/Bar.h:35:21: error: 'Foo' has not been declared

   virtual void workWithFoo(Foo *Foo);

                     ^
C:\PathWasHere\include/Bar.h:86:21: error: 'Foo' has not been declared

   virtual void workWithFoo(Foo *Foo);
                     ^
```

edit: forgot to say , i'm working with Bar in Foo too.

Comment: you missed `;` after `}` of every class

Comment: ...include `foo.h` in `bar.h` or forward declare `class Foo;`? You need to declare before any use.

Comment: @taocp sorry , i was writing it in stackoverflow

Comment: @crashmstr read my problem fully - i sad that i did try including foo.h in bar.h :|

Comment: Then you need to add that to your code, because everyone is going to tell you that's the problem.

Comment: @fhntv24 I saw that is what you said, but you don't *show* that in your code here. Thus I can only assume you did it wrong or did not actually do it (assuming it was not the issue that taocp points out).

Comment: @aruisdante alredy modified message

Comment: @crashmstr 1. its included in .cpp file 2. As i sad , i did try #include <Bar.h>

Comment: @fhntv24 OH WOW. You've drastically changed your question now that `Foo` uses `Bar` and vice versa (this was not there before!). Just forward declare the class so you can declare functions using a pointer to the class and include the header in the cpp files. Also, this now is a duplicate of at least one question here already.

Comment: Research "forward declarations".

Comment: @crashmstr OH WOW , THERE IS NO EVEN WORD 'DECLARED'. How i could find it , if its even called diffrently?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews ty , i know what it is. I didnt know what C++ need it for that cind of stuff ( was coding in Java , C# , Pascal. None of them need Forward for classes. Pascal need it for funcs , but not for classes. In pascal , it called public and private include - you could just include it privatly , and it would work perfect. )